# Representation of sums of series

Tags: real-analysis

Let a  series of real numbers $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$  be  absolutely convergent. Is it possible that the set of the sums of the series $$S:=\left \{\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\epsilon_na_n: \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \left(\epsilon_n \in \{-1,1\}\right)\right\}  $$ equals the union of two nonoverlapping intervals?

Comment: Do you exclude the case that $a_n =0$ for every $n$? If not, then can you cover $\{0\}$ with two non-overlapping intervals $\varnothing$ and $[0,0]$? I suppose I'm asking if there are any non-triviality assumptions in either the sums or the intervals you choose?

Comment: @Tom: Is $\emptyset$ an interval? I have never met such point. Could you give a reference?

Comment: If you define $(a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : a < x < b\}$ then take, for example, $(1,1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 1 < x < 1\} = \varnothing.$

Comment: @Tom: Empty intervals are not taken into consideration. Thank you for your interest to the question.

Comment: By saying "is it possible", do you mean if we can find such a sequence $(a_n)$ that $S$ is the union of two nonoverlapping intervals?

Comment: @Giraffe: Yes. Thank you for your interest to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote
$$L_m=\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty |a_n|\quad\text{and}\quad S_m:=\big\{\sum_{n=1}^m\epsilon_n a_n:\epsilon_n\in\{\pm 1\},\ \forall n\ge 1\big\}, \quad\forall m\ge 1.$$
By definition, 
$$S\subset T_m:=\bigcup_{x\in S_m}[x-L_m,x+L_m], \quad\forall m\ge 1.\tag{1}$$

> **Claim:** A sufficient condition for $S$ being a union of two disjoint closed
>   intervals is $$|a_1|>L_1\quad\text{and}\quad |a_m|\le L_m,\quad\forall m\ge 2.\tag{2}$$   Once $(2)$ holds,
>   $$S=T_1=[a_1-L_1,a_1+L_1]\cup [-a_1-L_1,-a_1+L_1].\tag{3}$$

**Proof:** When $|a_1|>L_1$, clearly $T_1$ is a union of two disjoint closed intervals, so it suffices to prove $(3)$ under the assumption $(2)$. $S\subset T_1$ is a sepecial case of $(1)$, so we only need to pick an arbitrary $x\in T_1$ and show that there is a sequence $\{\epsilon_n\}\subset\{\pm 1\}$, such that $x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\epsilon_n a_n$.

Let us use induction on $m$ to define $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_m$ and show that
$$|x-x_m|\le L_m,\quad\text{where}\quad x_m:=\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\epsilon_n a_n\in S_m.\tag{4}$$  When $m=1$, simply let $\epsilon_1$ be such that $x$ and $\epsilon_1a_1$ have the same sign and $(4)$ clearly holds. Now suppose that $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_m$ are defined and $(4)$ holds for $m$. Let $\epsilon_{m+1}$ be such that $x-x_m$ and $\epsilon_{m+1}a_{m+1}$ have the same sign(or one of them is $0$). Then from $|x-x_m|\le L_m$, $|a_{m+1}|\le L_{m+1}$ and the choice of $\epsilon_{m+1}$ we know that
$$|x-x_{m+1}|= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}|x-x_m|-|a_{m+1}|\le L_m-|a_{m+1}|=L_{m+1}, & if\  |x-x_m|\ge |a_{m+1}|\\|a_{m+1}|-|x-x_m|\le |a_{m+1}|\le L_{m+1},& if\  |x-x_m|\le |a_{m+1}|\end{array}\right.,
$$
so the induction is completed. By the definition of $\{\epsilon_n\}$ and $(4)$, we know that
$$|x-x_m|\le L_m,\quad \forall m\ge 1\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}|x-x_m|=0\Longrightarrow  x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\epsilon_n a_n\in S,$$
which completes the proof of $(3)$. $\qquad\square$

**Remark:**
If $|a_m|>L_m$ for every $m\ge 1$, then from $(1)$ it is easy to see that for every $m\ge 1$, $T_m$ is a disjoint union of $2^m$ closed intervals, and hence $S\subset \bigcap\limits_{m=1}^\infty T_m$ is a Cantor set.

Comment: Deep thought. You see the heart of the problem.

Comment: @user64494: Maybe I should mention that your question is closed related to "Bernoulli convolution", but since I am not familiar with that topic at all, I didn't discuss it in my answer.